# Delete all user attachments

Tags: buddypress

In buddypress when a user wants to delete their own account --> is possible to delete all their attachments entries and images uploaded using media?

Note:
Images are not attached to posts, because im not letting users create normal posts, they only can upload images using media.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about the posts to which they were attached? or the posts which the author wrote? any connection in between them?

Comment: No, thats not a problem in my case, because im not letting users create normal posts only upload images.

Comment: It can be done by hooking on to the hook for deleting the user, where we would fetch the attachment IDs and then call `wp delete attachment` for each of them. If there are quite a good number of images per user, a direct query would be better in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As media uploads are simly files with no related data stored, you can't do that unless you extend the user data and save the file names, etc. as user meta data. Simple answer: No, it doesn't work.